# Firestore delete old data without using cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud firestore collection of messages and I want to delete messages which are older than 24 hours. I am a student and I don't have a credit card so I can't use cloud functions. Are there any other ways or free services that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the admin sdk, build an executable in your chosen language, and then schedule a Cron job to run your utility every 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a custom user that has permission to delete them, you would use this like a bot and it simply runs queries to delete old files.
You just need to reference this users UID in your rules to have special permissions